# How to automatically delimit a column, then copy and pasting into new row? Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

my data set looks like this.

```
Column 1 - Column 2 - Column 3 - Column 4

  X      -   Y      -  A,B,C   -  F

  H      -   J      -  E,O,P   -  L
```

I want it to look like

```
Column 1 - Column 2 - Column 3 - Column 4

  X      -  Y       -  A      -  F

  X      -  Y       -  B      -  F

  X      -  Y       -  C      -  F

  H      -  J       -  E      -  L

  H      -  J       -  O      -  L

  H      -  J       -  P      -  L
```

MY current process is super manual with manually delimiting column 3, then manually posting the line 3 times, and deleting the columns I don't need.

Please let me know if there is a way to do this more automatically! I would prefer a formula that I can use, since I've never used VBA, but I can attempt to understand a VBA Macro as well!

Best,

Answer (score 0):

How many lines do you have? Is this a constant number of columns and row?

Comment: Hey! The rows are variable, but the data comes in the same column format!